# Getting attempt to call a nil value (field 'maxn') error

Tags: lua

```
mytable = setmetatable({1,2,3}, {
    __add = function(mytable, newtable)

     for i = 1, table.maxn(newtable) do
            table.insert(mytable, table.maxn(mytable)+1, newtable[i])
    end
    return mytable
end
})

secondtable = {4,5,6}

mytable = mytable + secondtable

for k,v in ipairs(mytable) do
    print(k,v)
end
```

I'm getting this error when I run it in terminal :

```
lua: metatables4.lua:6: attempt to call a nil value (field 'maxn')
stack traceback:
    metatables4.lua:6: in metamethod '__add'
    metatables4.lua:15: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

But when I try to run it on tutorialspoint compiler it runs.

```
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
```

This should be my output. I couldn't pinpoint what is exactly the problem here since it runs on tutorialspoint coding ground lua compiler.

What should I change for it to work on my terminal ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Lua 5.2 Reference Manual - 8.2 – Changes in the Libraries](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#8.2):

> Function table.maxn is deprecated. Write it in Lua if you really need
>   it.

You are running a more recent version of Lua than tutorialspoint.

You can add the following code at the top of your script that will make it work in Lua 5.1+ versions:

```
table.maxn = table.maxn or function(t) return #t end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use  `#newtable` instead of `table.maxn(newtable)`.